# list with numbers and strings to single string python

Tags: python, string, list

How do I print a list that has numbers and strings to a single string?
For example, I have this list: `["(",3,"+",4,"-",3,")"]`, I would like it to be printed as :`(3+4-4).` I tried to use the join command, but I keep having issues with the numbers.

Comment: What was the issue with the numbers? Isn't that what the question is about? Pretty sure there will be a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast the ints to str, `str.join` expects strings:

```
l = ["(",3,"+",4,"-",3,")"]

print("".join(map(str,l)))
(3+4-3)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
print("".join([str(x) for x in l]))
```

To delimit each element  with a space use:

```
print(" ".join(map(str,l)))
```

Comment: that actually did the trick, but, is there a way to have it create a space between each list element? I'm doing a RPN calculator, and when I return the results I must show 3 4 + 3 -

Comment: oooh I see, that makes a lot of sense xD, I've been trying it for hours, you really saved my life

Comment: No worries, glad it helped and that I could save your life with code ;)